# Why am i getting keyerror in Pandas Python

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to get the maximum number of cities('CTYNAME') in a state('STNAME') using PANDAS
I have a dataframe

```
df_filtered = census_df.copy().filter(items=['SUMLEV','STNAME','CTYNAME'])
df_filtered = df_filtered.set_index(['STNAME'])
state_df['STNAME'] = df.index.tolist()
state_df['STNAME'] = state_df['STNAME'].drop_duplicates()
state_df = state_df['STNAME'].dropna()
state_df = pd.DataFrame(state_df)
state_df.set_index(['STNAME'])

for state in state_df:
    state_df['COUNT'] = df.loc[state].count()
```

For some reason even though I set the index to the state name ('STNAME'), the index is a bunch of integers instead of the name of the state (ie Alaska, Utah, etc).

And when I try to run the code it is giving me a Key Error

```
KeyError: 'the label [STNAME] is not in the [index]'
```

Answer (score 1):

Your index is not set. try this.

Edit the code:

```
df_filtered = df_filtered.set_index('STNAME')
```

Comment: @Linkx_lair. Try this. Hope this will help.

Comment: I tried that but when i try to print out the list of indexes using index.tolist(), it shows a list of integers instead. I don't know what is going on and why I can't set the index to be the state name('STNAME')

Answer (score 0):

When you do `for _ in df` you are actually iterating over the headers.
Try iterating over the series `state_df['STNAME']`

```
for state in state_df['STNAME']:
    # do stuff here with state
```

Otherwise, use `state_df.iterrows()` to iterate over the rows. If "STNAME" is your index, you can do this:

```
for row in state_df.iterrows():
    state_name = row[0]
    # do stuff here with state name
```

Comment: How do I iterate using the iterrows? I tried using the next(state_df.iterrows())[1] and for some reason it keeps giving me the same record "Alabama".

Comment: When I do print(state_df), it shows a list of integers on the left and the STNAME (State name) on the right - which are all unique. I just can't figure out how to iterate over the state names...

Also I tried doing while(~(next(state_df.iterrows())[1].empty())):  but that threw a typeError "Bool" object is not callable

Comment: I've updated my answer. Try iterating through the 'STNAME' column as my first example shows.